# How to get custom shaders and texture packs on Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-addons

I want to be able to get texture packs and shaders on Minecract Bedrock Edition without having to buy them on the marketplace. Is there A way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `.mcpack` will do.

- For **iOS**, I recommend [Addons For Minecraft](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/addons-for-minecraft/id1170340094)
- For **Windows 10/Android**, I recommend using [MCPEDL](https://mcpedl.com).

<sub>Note that the two places I mentioned have a lot of the same content, with MCPEDL having a bit more.</sub>

For a version not mentioned (i.e. PS4) the marketplace is your only option.